# How do I use SVG Path commands?

Tags: javascript, svg, path

This is a more simple question, but I have been using SVG Paths inside my code. I know that using this code (L 100 100) will draw a line to the point 100,100. I want to know if there is a way to draw a line, not to a specific point, but rather go a direction a certain amount of units?

Comment: Upper case is for absolute position, lowercase for relative. So `l` is what you are looking for

Comment: There is no angle + distance option - you have to do either absolute or relative x,y